# Firestore transaction and batch?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that register a client. The function takes care of creating the user, the users company, and adding some meta data about the user. However, the fragile thing in the function is that if one of the requests fails, the user is stuck and can't sign up again - I was told that I could solve this by using a transactions or batch. I've looked into writeBatch() and batches, but it seems you need to have a reference to a document that you want to update. However, in my case, I'm creating new documents - How can i refactor this into be a transaction/batches? What I have so far is this:

```
const registerUser = async (user: RegisterUserData) => {
    try {
      const batch = writeBatch(db);

      const test = await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
        const userDoc = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, user.password);
        const userId = userDoc.user.uid;

        const companyRef = batch.set(doc(db, 'companies'), {
          title: user.companyName,
          userCount: 1
        });

        let isAdmin = false;
        if (await setUserAsAdmin(userId)) {
          isAdmin = true;
        }

        batch.set(doc(db, 'users'), {
          email: user.email,
          userId: userId,
          firstName: user.firstName,
          lastName: user.lastName,
          isAdmin: isAdmin,
          role: isAdmin ? 'admin' : 'coach',
          clientCount: 0,
          // companyId: companyRef.id
        });
        await batch.commit();
      });
      console.log('test', test)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error', e);
      throw new Error('cant register user: ' + e);
    }
  };
```

The original function before my refactor looks like this (And is working):

```
const registerUser = async (user: RegisterUserData) => {
    try {
      const createUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, user.password);
      const createdCompany = await createUserCompany({
        title: user.companyName,
        userCount: 1
      });
      let isAdmin = false;
      const adminSet = await setUserAsAdmin(createUser.user.uid);
      if (adminSet) {
        isAdmin = true;
      }
      await createUserMetaData({
        email: user.email,
        userId: createUser.user.uid,
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        isAdmin: isAdmin,
        role: isAdmin ? 'admin' : 'coach',
        clientCount: 0,
        companyId: createdCompany.id
      });
      return createUser;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error('cant register user' + e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot include a call to the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method from the Auth part of the JS SDK in a Firestore transaction. As a matter of fact, the set of atomic operations that you can include in a Firestore transaction can only be Firestore operations (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.transaction) for the exact list).

So while you can include your two Firestore writes in a batched write it is not possible to include the user creation in the transaction.

---

One possible solution if you want to avoid the (rare) case where the user is created but not the Firestore docs is to regularly check for this case, for example with a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) which corrects the problem.

Comment: Hello @envy, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help... Ended up not doing it in transactions/batches, and have a cloud function check whether the docs were created or not